# What makes a deterministic finite automaton different from another one?

Tags: combinatorics, automata

I have been given the following question: How many different automata $\newcommand{\perm}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}A = \perm{Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_o, F}$ is it possible to form, when the number of states $\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}\abs Q = m$ and the size of the alphabet $\abs\Sigma = n$.

Now this should probably be a simple exercise in combinatorics, but the problem is, I don't know what makes two automata different. What exactly is meant by this?

I can state the following:

1. The automata all have at least the same states $Q$, alphabet $\Sigma$, initial state $q_0$ and final states $F$.
2. We have $\abs Q\abs\Sigma$ different $Q$--$\Sigma$ pairs, assuming we can transition out of each state with each of the alphabet.
3. At the same time, as the state transition function $\delta$ maps from $Q \times\Sigma$ to $Q$, we have $\abs Q^{\abs Q\abs\Sigma}$ different kinds of state transition functions.
4. Assuming every state in $Q$ can be an initial state, the total number of state functions then has to be multiplied by the number of states, so we have $\abs Q \times \abs Q ^{\abs Q \abs\Sigma}$.
5. The power set of the states $Q$, $\mathit 2^{Q}$, has $2^{\abs Q}$ elements. This essentially gives us the number of combinations of states $F$ that are reachable from the start state in the state transition chain of each machine.

Taking all of these fact into account, I end up with $\abs Q \times \abs Q^{\abs Q \abs\Sigma} \times 2^{\abs Q}$ "different" machines. But are these machines really different?

Comment: I think this question is better asked of your professor. If it were up to me, I would say two machines are "the same" iff they are isomorphic as labeled graphs (vertices _and_ edges are labeled here). But there's an argument to be made for allowing permutations of the vertices, since that makes the counting slightly harder, and is a more realistic question. It would be completely unreasonable to call two machines "the same" if they accept the same language. Unfortunately, I don't think anyone can really say what your professor wants besides your professor.

Comment: Hmm. The thing is, we have actually looked at things from the semantics (language) point of view thus far. Two regular expressions are "the same" (or equivalent) if they generate the same langauge. Beyond that, there is no information in the material concerning this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thorough discussion of your problem can be found in the article [1], which also contains an extensive bibliography.

[1] Frédérique Bassino and Cyril Nicaud, [Enumeration and Random Generation of Accessible Automata](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~nicaud/articles/tcs07.pdf), *Theor. Comp. Sci.* **381**(1-3): 86-104 (2007)